# Adobe Air - Icon file is missing error

Tags: flash, air, air-android

I published an app to Air 2.5 (.air) from Adobe Flash CS 5 and afterwards also to Air Android (.apk)
Since then I receive this error message if I try to publish as .air again:

> Error creating files. Icon file is missing.

I tried to delete and recreate the folder and pathes but the error still appears.

How to fix that?

Comment: I removed the Flex tag; because it is impossible hard to use Flex inside Flash Professional; and I suspect you are not doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
it seems like Flash is caching the need for the different icons (air packages ask for different icon sizes than air for android apks).
```

The only way I was able to continue was to rename my apk name, package name, etc and NOT specify icons anymore if i wanted to test the project as both an air package and an apk.

- I just switched over an app from iOS to AIR for Android publishing and was getting this icon error.  Deleting the xxx_app.xml file fixed it immediately.  Might have been some extra tags in there from the iOS build that were being read during publishing but not cleaned up when I made the switch... haven't diffed them so not sure what might have caused the error..

> AIR Application error code 303: The icon files specified in the
>   application descriptor must be added to the package by including them
>   among the files listed on the ADT command line. Icon files are not
>   added automatically.

Comment: Thank you very much! Deleting the xxx_app.xml file  worked! An additional closing and reboot  of the development  environment was needed also.